# Incorrect page numbering in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

For any chapter I added with `\addcontentsline` there is an incorrect page numbering in the table of contents. Is there someone who may help me solve this problem? The other chapters seem to be right...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

\usepackage{acronym}     
\usepackage{anyfontsize} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures\vfill
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables\vfill

\chapter{test}
\chapter{test}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have linked a question/answer to texwelt several times because you are doing stuff incorrect. Did you mind clicking on that link? Or did you think i like to leave links to some questions? http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4035/wie-kann-ich-verzeichnisse-im-inhalt-auffuhren

Answer (score 2):

This is cause by using `\vfill` in an attempt to create new pages, which it really doesn't do. It is used for instance if you want some content on the top of a page, and some other content on the bottom, with some space between. Then you would apply `\vfill` here.

For creating new pages, you could use `\clearpage`, `\newpage` or `\pagebreak`.

Also, in the class `scrbook` you can use the parameter `listof=totoc`, and it will add all entries to toc that way. Here is your code, using that:

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt, open = any, listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm, footskip=10mm} 
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

\usepackage{acronym}     
\usepackage{anyfontsize} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{test}
\chapter{test}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please click the link in the comments above.

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't speak german, sorry.

Comment: Right, my fault, sorry. Still, you will notice that there is no `\addcontentsline` in the solution.

Comment: @Johannes_B see updated answer. Also, your solution uses a different documentclass. Note that there are other problems in the question, than simply adding the parts to the ToC.